# Can I track the position of an element on flutter and display measurements and distances as on figma?

Tags: flutter, package, editor, layer

[Here's what I'm actually trying to do in a flutter stack with several widgets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHQvE.png)

Is there a plugin or package that can do this? Any help would be appreciated.
I would also like to have examples of applications or sites implementing this with flutter.
Thanks

Comment: I don't think that anyone made something that in 100% would implements your design - seems that you have to do that by yourself (with the help of `CustomPaint` widget)

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer. It's It's a real shame there's no such package.